# Setting up automatic color correction

Tags: photoshop, color-correction

I am editing a batch of pictures in which many of them have a color cast. What is the best method to generate the correct color balance for all the pictures without spending a lot of time editing each picture individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using photoshop, select all of them in Adobe Raw Converter and then select your white balance by either adjusting the sliders or using the color balance eye dropper tool.

I'm assuming the use of photoshop since your question is tagged with photoshop.

Comment: Yes but what if the OP isn't shooting in RAW?

Comment: @HeatherWalters - You can still open JPEG Files in RAW and adjust them.

Comment: +1 for that, did not know that.  Thanks!